# TSQL create new query based on previous query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, resultset

I have a table called PRICE with two columns, unitPrice and resellerId. From my application, I use the following code (pseudo) to query the unitPrice for a given reseller. Basically I use the unitPrice if the resellerId presents in the table. Otherwise I use the default unitPrice (for a special reseller with Id 0)

```
resultSet = select unitPrice from PRICE where resellerId=123
if(resultSet.isEmpty()){
   resultSet = select unitPrice from PRICE where resellerId=0
}
```

This works all fine.

My question is if there is a way in TSQL to combine the two queries above into one statement that returns the unitPrice without the application code checking the condition (i.e. without checking resultSet.isEmpty())?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to return one row, then you want to do a prioritization:

```
select top 1 price
from unitPrice
where resellerId in (123, 0)
order by (case when resellerId = 0 then 1 else 0 end);
```